# SQL - Adding a new column or concatenate to a table based on conditional values

Tags: sql

I am very (very!!!) new to SQL and I am struggling with this scenario:

I have a master table named **tbl_fin_View** (with many columns and rows) and one of the columns is named **profit_center_code** (there are over 2000 profit center codes).

I need to add the **profit_center_description** to this table which is available in another table named **tbl_profit_center_list** (this table contains the same profit center code as the **tbl_fin_view** plus the description) ....so I need to do either:

1) concatenate the description to the code in the same cell under **profit_center_code** column OR
2) create a new column (can be the very last column in the **tbl_fin_view**) with the **profit_center_description**.

I added the tables for reference[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y92jK.png)

Any help is super appreciated!
Thanks in advance
Simone

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help other people understand your question.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: The fact that it is called ...view suggests its not a table at all, but a view based on the other tables. Which means you should be updating the view definition (which will be sql). As to whether to include a new column or concatenate, it depends entirely on what the users of it want to see. They may find it easier if the number of columns doesnt change (like if they are using this in excel as the basis for something else), or they may prefer to break them out. It would be *more normal* (to make a arbitrary judgement) to add new column to the view.

Comment: it is not a view...I just named it view... it is a table and this is my own server, users dont have access to any of the tables here.. they only see the output which is done in BI tool

Comment: I'd also suggest using a view and joining the two tables. Do not duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the standard SQL script and you can use the same logic for any database with changes in Syntax-

Option 1: Update the profit_center_code column with concatenate values from details table

```
UPDATE A
SET A.profit_center_code  = A.profit_center_code +' '+ B.profit_center_details
FROM tbl_fin_view A
INNER JOIN profit_center_description B 
    ON A.profit_center_code = B.profit_center_code
```

> Please make sure all profit_center_code details are available in the details table. Other case source table will be updated with NULL in case the code not found in the details table.

Option 2: For new column created in tbl_fin_view  table-

```
UPDATE A
SET A.profit_center_details  = B.profit_center_details
FROM tbl_fin_view A
INNER JOIN profit_center_description B 
    ON A.profit_center_code = B.profit_center_code
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rabbani, somehow it says that the column for the description is an invalid object... dont I have to make a reference to where that column is since it's a different table? it is not part of the fin view table